# how can I Obtain ClientContext in office 365 with fixed credentials (do not prompt user)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365, sharepoint-object-model

I am prototyping a tool that runs every few minutes and goes off to an office 365 site and to retrieve and then process information.

At the moment I have started with the MSDN guide **"Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based Authentication"** which points to a very helpful code sample that gets a clientcontext object based on a user logging in and then extracts the cookie.

I want to be able to run my code within task scheduler, so that you will be able to specify the office username and password in a configuration somewhere.

Does anyone have any code that will do this or a starting point.
something like

```
using (ClientContext ctx = SomeClass.GetContext(targetSiteUrl, username, password))
{
    if (ctx != null)
    {
        //dostuffhere
    }
}
```

I have seen this blog post [Automatic Login for SharePoint using Claims authentication](http://craigsdotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/automatic-login-for-sharepoint-using.html) but the code on the site doesn't appear to be complete / I cannot get it working

Just to note that I am referring to the current release of office 365 (based on 2010) and not the newly available beta of 2013

Comment: I may have found the answer. I will be in a position to implement on Wednesday this week. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

Answer (score 1):

so, are you wanting to allow a user to access something without them being a registered user in SharePoint? if so, you may want to look into elevating the current users privileges in code.

Comment: That is not quite what i'm trying to do. I don't think you can elevate code via the Client side object model. I still need a way of getting the initial clientContext object

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm that this post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx) has the answer. ou use the MSOnlineHelper class to do the headless authentication

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) class to instantiate clientContext.Credentials.

> The SharePointOnlineCredentials class represents an object that
>   provides credentials to access SharePoint Online resources.